# neo4j java program example fails with NoClassDefFoundError for

Tags: java, maven, neo4j

I am trying to run the basic neo4j java program as mentioned here (https://neo4j.com/developer/java/), using maven.

Although I could compile successfully, but when I run it, I get a runtime exception indicating that the program was unable to find a class, as shown below..

```
java com.ravi.nFourJ.App
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/driver/v1/TransactionWork
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.driver.v1.TransactionWork
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

This is my pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ravi.nFourJ</groupId>
  <artifactId>n4-java</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>n4-java</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-kernel -->
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
     <version>3.5.0-alpha03</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I did mvn compile, which created a folder called 'target' under the project dir.

```
└── target
    ├── classes
    │   └── com
    │       └── ravi
    │           └── nFourJ
    │               ├── App$1.class
    │               └── App.class
    └── maven-status
        └── maven-compiler-plugin
            └── compile
                └── default-compile
                    ├── createdFiles.lst
                    └── inputFiles.lst
```

After I navigate to the "target/classes" directory and run the program

```
java com.ravi.nFourJ.App
```

it gives the above mentioned error.

1. Am I doing something wrong here?
2. In which dependency is the package/class "org/neo4j/driver/v1/TransactionWork" found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `java com.ravi.nFourJ.App` you are runnning the class but without any classpath (ie. deps).

I recommand you to use this command instead : `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.ravi.nFourJ.App"`